# 5 volts to breadboard not working

Tags: arduino, led

I am trying to verify I have power and verify positive and negative wires from cyberpower plug.  I can't get this led to light up.  I am going to attach two pictures one of the breadboard setup and one of the power module.  The power module has a sliding switch that I have set to 5 volts.  The resistor is 680 ohm the power unit is up to 1300 mA.

The long leg of the led is plugged in next to the resistor.  I have switched the black and red from positive to negative on the board.

I know this is probably a dumb question but we all have to start somewhere.

Thanks
Mark

[image: breadboard setup]

[image: power unit]

Comment: Circuitry pictures are better asked at [arduino.se]. This site is for code related questions.

Comment: This is a very poor candidate for Arduino.SE, seeing as how there is no Arduino involved. It could be asked at Electronics.SE, but get a DMM.

Comment: Honestly guys I'm a programmer and had no idea which tags to add to this question.  I chose arduino and led thinking that the people who are on those boards could probably diagnose my problem sorry if it was wrong

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.  You might try one of the electronics sites in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well one multi - meter later I discovered that the 5 on the slider of the power supply must have been .5 because when set to 4.5 higher up the scale the multimeter shows 5 volts and everything works.  I now have a esp8266 running from a nodemcu .9 devboard running an mqtt client working off the breadboard power subscribing and publishing. which was todays goal.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Some breadboards have gaps in the middle of the power rails that need to be jumpered. Use a DMM to verify that this is the case on yours.